# Parent Category with all Child Category's Data MYSQL query to Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Hi guys as this query i get to work in MYSQL but i want this to convert in Codeigniter Active records.

Basically i have 3 tables

- suppliers(with intCat, intCity, *)
- category(with intId, strCategory, intParent)
- tblcitylist( with city_id, city_name)

Query:

```
SELECT category.strCategory AS strParent, Query3. *  FROM (

SELECT tblcitylist.city_name AS strCity, Query2. *  FROM (

SELECT Query1.intParent, Query1.strCategory, suppliers. *  FROM (

SELECT category.strCategory, category.intId, category.intParent FROM
category WHERE ( ( ( category.intParent ) =51 ) ) ) AS Query1 INNER
JOIN suppliers ON Query1.intId = suppliers.intCat ) AS Query2 INNER
JOIN tblcitylist ON Query2.intCity = tblcitylist.city_id ) AS Query3
INNER JOIN category ON Query3.intParent = category.intId
```

I want to get suppliers(with it's category and parent category name(strCategory, strParent) and city name (city_name as strCity)) from all child category of parent category(51).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and you asking ppl to do it for you!!. what have you tried please?

Comment: this has nothing to do with codeigniter or activerecord

Answer (score 1):

This will return parent , their categories and subcategories by pass parent id

```
function get_parent_child_subchild($category_id,$all_cate=array())
{
    if(!is_array($category_id))
    {           
        $this->db->where('parent_id', $category_id);
        $all_cate[]=$category_id;
    }
    else
    {           
        $this->db->where_in('parent_id', $category_id);
    }        
    $get_categories= $this->db->get('newcategory'); 
    if($get_categories->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $categories_vales=$get_categories->result(); 
        $new_subcat = array();
        foreach($categories_vales as $cate_val)
        {
            $category_id=$cate_val->category_id;
            array_push($new_subcat,$category_id);
        }
        $all_cate = array_merge($all_cate,$new_subcat);         
        if(count($new_subcat)>0)
        {
            $this->get_parent_child_subchild($new_subcat,$all_cate);
        }   
    }   

    return $all_cate;
}
```